# How to specialize mapM for IO in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, io-monad

Say I have a task that represents some computation from `k` to `v` where some inputs have to be fetched externally.

```
newtype Task k v = Task { run ∷ ∀ f. Monad f ⇒ (k → f v) → f v }
```

For some tasks `mapM` will be used, e.g. to fetch multiple keys. I want to specialize `mapM` for some monads. Specifically for the `IO` monad I want to use `Control.Concurrent.Async.mapConcurrently` to perform IO actions concurrently.

My first instinct is to introduce a wrapper type

```
newtype AsyncIO a = AsyncIO { io :: IO a }
```

and then introduce

```
instance Monad AsyncIO
```

However this doesn't work because in the current GHC implementation `mapM` is defined in term of `traverse`, which is in `Traversable`.

Is there an elegant solution for this?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "for some tasks `mapM` will be used". Could you show an example of such a `Task`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `traverse` only needs an `Applicative`. You can make `mapM` do its actions in parallel by using an alternative `Applicative` for `IO` (this is how `mapConcurrently` is implemented). However, this `Applicative` does not have a lawful `Monad` instance: `(>>=)` and the other `Monad` operations will not be consistent with `(<*>)` and the other `Applicative` operations. E.g. `mf >>= \f -> mx >>= \x -> return (f x)` will not be equivalent to `mf <*> mx`, as `(>>=)` cannot execute its arguments in parallel but `(<*>)` will. (You probably could create a working `Monad` instance by using `unsafeInterleaveIO`, but, well, `unsafeInterleaveIO`.)

One of the things you can do is pass `Task`s an `Applicative` functor, separate from the `Monad`, and then provide a natural transformation to inject every computation in the former into the latter. The lookup function should also be in the `Applicative` context.

```
newtype Task k v = Task { run ∷ ∀f f'. (Monad f, Applicative f')
                              ⇒ (∀a. f' a → f a)
                              → (k → f' v) → f v
                        }
```

If you don't have any special `Applicative` involved, just use `id` as the natural transformation:

```
runSimple ∷ Monad f ⇒ Task k v → (k → f v) → f v
runSimple t = run t id
```

And for `IO`, the special `Applicative` functor is already nicely packaged up for you in `Control.Concurrent.Async.Concurrently`:

```
runWithParallelIO ∷ Task k v → (k → IO v) → IO v
runWithParallelIO t lookup = run t runConcurrently (Concurrently . lookup)
```

You'd write a `Task` like this:

```
task ∷ Task _k _v
task = Task go
  where go exec lookup = do _
                            xs <- exec $ mapM lookup _
                            _
```

If you find yourself writing a `Task` that simply does not benefit from having the separate `Monad` and `Applicative` contexts, you can use this smart constructor

```
taskSimple ∷ (∀f. Monad f ⇒ (k → f v) → f v) → Task k v
taskSimple r = Task (\exec lookup -> r (exec . lookup))
```

to avoid wrapping every `lookup` in `exec`. AFAICT, `runSimple . taskSimple = id`, and `taskSimple . runSimple` is idempotent.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I need. I knew in Haskell there has to be an elegant higher-order solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Have run take `mapM` or `mapConcurrently` as an additional argument, or for possibly less passing as an implicit parameter, though I'm not sure whether the latter will clash with f's quantification.